# How to avoid changing a bean name during refactoring if it's injected with @Autowired + @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

By default, beans annotated with `@Component` can be resolved via short class name with the first letter lower-cased, e.g. `class x.y.z.Foo -> "foo"`. If we have more than one bean implementing the same interface, injected bean should be specified via `@Qualifier` annotation like `@Qualifier("foo")`.

However, upon refactoring, the bean can be renamed from `Foo` to `Bar` and all the references inside `@Qualifier` should be renamed accordingly,  from `@Qualifier("foo")` to `@Qualifier("bar")`, otherwise, we get an error on the runtime.

Is there a way to facilitate the search of such beans before runtime, or at least, get a compile-time error or warning?

The best way I see now is creating a registry class and keep all bean names there:

```
public final class BeanNames {
     public static final String FOO = "foo";
     ...
}

@Component(BeanNames.FOO)
class Foo { ... }

class Baz {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier(BeanNames.FOO)
   Foo foo;
   ...
```

Comment: My question:  why are you making such drastic naming changes to your code such that a bean previously named "foo" would ever be called "bar"?

Comment: even if you refactor the bean it should work  without renaming the value inside qualifier. Another way is rather than autowiring the interface autowire the implemented class.

Comment: @Makoto the situation is even worse if the class name changes slightly (e.g it's just a fix of a typo) because you can easily overlook it inside `@Qualifier`

Comment: @NawnitSen 1) It won't if you rename the bean injected. 2) Autowiring the implemented class leads to tight coupling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom qualifier annotation that builds upon the standard `@Qualifier`:

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
         ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface QualifierFoo {}
```

Then annotate your component class with it:

```
@Component
@QualifierFoo
class Foo { ... }
```

And inject it like any other bean with a qualifier:

```
class Baz {
   @Autowired
   @QualifierFoo
   Foo foo;
   ...
```

Then when you refactor `Foo` to `Bar` all you would need to do is refactor the qualifier name from `QualifierFoo` to `QualifierBar`.